# Как вывести последние сообщения сверху вниз mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

Ребята, как правильно вывести последние 10 сообщений сверху вниз?

```
SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Выводит, последних 10 сообщений, но мне нужно сверху вниз что бы выводило.

Comment: А как же оно их выводит если не сверху вниз ? расположение результатов на экране от sql запроса никак не зависит...

Comment: мне нужно что бы последние сообщение были внизу, а не в верху последние 10

Comment: @Members, так кто вам мешает цикл на javascript (раз он у вас указан в тегах) сделать в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд переворачивать пользовательский вывод в sql запросе, это довольно изврещенный спороб обработки данных, но тем не менее:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM Messages 
                ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS t1 
ORDER BY id;
```

ИМХО, более логично, подготавливать данные для вывода пользователю на стороне клиента. Для этого есть функция [`Array.prototype.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).